# jq - output array as csv followed by other fields in the object

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json layout:

test.json

```
{
  "end": 9,
  "previous_page_uri": null,
  "messages": [
    {
      "error_message": null,
      "num_media": "1",
      "status": "received"
    },
    {
      "error_message": null,
      "num_media": "2",
      "status": "received"
    }
],
        "end1": "end page 1",
        "end2": "end page 2"
}
```

I want to output the .messages object as csv, followed by the "end1" value.

Is there a way to do that in jq?

To produce the csv:

```
 jq '.messages[] | [.error_message, .num_media, .status]|@csv' test.json
```

which produces this:

```
",\"1\",\"received\""
",\"2\",\"received\""
```

How can I add .end1?

Comment: Please clarify the requirements (do you mean: "add .end1" as a CSV value at the end of each line of output?), and also show the expected output. See [mcve] for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `,` [Comma](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Comma:,) to concatenate the output of two filters and `( )` [Parenthesis](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Parenthesis) to specify them separately.  For example with the sample input you provided the filter

```
( .messages[] | [.error_message, .num_media, .status] | @csv ), .end1
```

generates

```
",\"1\",\"received\""
",\"2\",\"received\""
"end page 1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nU@7DoMwDNz5CitTK0VIsLVT/wMhhMCqUvFqTFgo357agSK6VV0c3118Pj@e3p8gbpGovCNlObwgi9Ha3hYbqSHuXMuoNiX3NJajI/l3q2iCM1PY1Yn3cwSguFVXuGjpB4uT6R0VA7sUzhpWOtc0QfxsZC5jDDCHKhbH5YeRIO5JWFCJ2vk1lZAWKzQT1ipIi/7XPP3BnGuut7MT0fkFuRbWaILTLz5V0fIG)

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew there HAD to be a way. I had tried to use a comma, but didn't know about the ().